# How can i programatacally change pristine and valid state of controls of form in angular2 ? I am using ngModel to bind data

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Below is my html in Angular2 component:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
<div>
   <input #txtCityLocation="ngModel" id=txtCityLocation name=txtCityLocation type="text"  [(ngModel)]="city" required >
   <div [hidden]="txtCityLocation.valid || txtCityLocation.pristine">City is required</div>
   <label for="txtState">STATE</label>               
   <input #txtState="ngModel" id=txtState name=txtState type="text"  [(ngModel)]="state" >
   <label for="txtCountry" >COUNTRY</label>               
   <input #txtCountry="ngModel" id=txtCountry name=txtCountry type="text"  [(ngModel)]="country" required >
   <div [hidden]="txtCountry.valid || txtCountry.pristine">Country is required</div>
   <label for="txtPostalCode" >POSTAL CODE</label>               
   <input #txtPostalCode="ngModel" id=txtPostalCode name=txtPostalCode type="text"  [(ngModel)]="postalcode" required >
   <div [hidden]="txtPostalCode.valid || txtPostalCode.pristine">Postcode is required</div>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="register($event)" name="btnReady" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Ready</button>
```

And code :

```
export class MyComponent {
    public googleLocation: GoogleLocation = new GoogleLocation();

    private city : string;
    private state : string;
    private country : string;
    private postalcode : string;

    private onNotify(googleLocation: GoogleLocation) {
        this.googleLocation = googleLocation;               // setting a valid location like Mumbai,Maharashtra,India
        this.city = this.googleLocation.Locality;           // I want txtCityLocation.valid = true and txtCityLocation.pristine = false
        this.state = this.googleLocation.Region;            // I want txtState.valid = true and txtState.pristine = false
        this.country = this.googleLocation.CountryName;     // I want txtCountry.valid = true and txtCountry.pristine = false
        this.postalcode = this.googleLocation.PostalCode;   // I want txtPostalCode.valid = true and txtPostalCode.pristine = false
    }

    Reset() : void
    {
        this.googleLocation = new GoogleLocation();         // Assigning blank values
        this.city = this.googleLocation.Locality;           // I want txtCityLocation.pristine = true
        this.state = this.googleLocation.Region;            // I want txtState.pristine = true
        this.country = this.googleLocation.CountryName;     // I want txtCountry.pristine = true
        this.postalcode = this.googleLocation.PostalCode;   // I want txtPostalCode.pristine = true so that i can display error message in proper situation

    }
}
```

As mentioned in comments on reset button click, my all data fields are set to blank, but that does not change control.pristine or control.touched and control.valid properties.

I want form to be rest to a new form when user clicks Reset button.And show proper error messages in correct condition.

As seen in code, I display error message when control.pristine = false and control.valid = false. 
i.e. error msg should not be displayed when form is loaded first time or when user clicks reset button.
And Ready button should be enabled when data is set through code setting control.valid = true.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be better off using a `formGroup` as it make it fairly simple to transfer the `formControls` to variables and modify the controls within your code.

There are multiple was of achieving this.  You may find a different way you prefer.

Here is an example of your code written up using `formGroup` and `formControls`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
// import GoogleLocation

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <form [formGroup]="formData">
        <div>
            <input id=txtCityLocation formControlName=city type="text" required >
            <div [hidden]="city.valid || city.pristine">City is required</div>

            <label for="txtState">STATE</label>               
            <input id=txtState formControlName=state type="text" >

            <label for="txtCountry" >COUNTRY</label>               
            <input id=txtCountry formControlName=country type="text" required >
            <div [hidden]="country.valid || country.pristine">Country is required</div>

            <label for="txtPostalCode" >POSTAL CODE</label>               
            <input id=txtPostalCode formControlName=postalcode type="text" required >
            <div [hidden]="postalcode.valid || postalcode.pristine">Postcode is required</div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" (click)="register($event)" name="btnReady" [disabled]="!formData.valid">Ready</button>
    </form>`
})
export class MyComponent {
    public googleLocation: GoogleLocation = new GoogleLocation();

    private city: FormControl;
    private state: FormControl;
    private country: FormControl;
    private postalcode: FormControl;

    private formData;

    constructor() {

        // Create Form Group with all input fields.
        this.formData = new FormGroup({
            city: new FormControl(null),
            state: new FormControl(null),
            country: new FormControl(null),
            postalcode: new FormControl(null)
        })

        // Assign form controls to variables.
        this.city = this.formData.controls.city;
        this.state = this.formData.controls.state;
        this.country = this.formData.controls.country;
        this.postalcode = this.formData.controls.postalcode;

    }

    private onNotify(googleLocation: GoogleLocation) {
        this.googleLocation = googleLocation;               // setting a valid location like Mumbai,Maharashtra,India

        this.city.setValue(this.googleLocation.Locality);   // Set city value equal to googleLocation.Locality
        this.city.markAsDirty();                            // Mark State as dirty (pristine = false)

        this.state.setValue(this.googleLocation.Region);    // Repeat for each field.
        this.state.markAsDirty();

        this.country.setValue(this.googleLocation.CountryName);
        this.country.markAsDirty();

        this.postalcode.setValue(this.googleLocation.PostalCode);
        this.postalcode.markAsDirty();
    }

    Reset() : void
    {
        this.googleLocation = new GoogleLocation();         // Assigning blank values

        this.city.setValue(null);                           // Set city value equal to null
        this.city.markAsPristine();                         // Mark State as pristine (dirty = true)

        this.state.setValue(null);                          // Repeat for each field.
        this.state.markAsPristine();

        this.country.setValue(null);
        this.country.markAsPristine();

        this.postalcode.setValue(null);
        this.postalcode.markAsPristine();

    }

}
```

Keep in mind, you could refactor this code to utilize for-loops to make it a little less verbose.  I chose not to in order to be mode deliberate with that was happening with each line.

You can also get the values out of each `formControl` by using `.value`.

```
// Example, both will return the current value of the city input.

this.city.value

    //or

this.form.controls.city.value
```

Here is a link to the Angular 2 docs that also provide an example of `FormGroup` and `FormControl`.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControlName-directive.html

You may also want to check out `AbstractControl`.  It is the base class for both `FormGroup` and `FormControl` and is primarily where the functions used in the code I provided are coming from. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html

Comment: `this.<FormGroup>.controls.<FormControl>.markAsDirty();`

Comment: `this.<FormGroup>.controls.<FormControl>.setValue(<value>);`